# Is there way to split a matrix into multiple matrices?

Tags: matlab, matrix

Is there a way to split a 300x400 matrix into 8 300x50 matrices?

Answer (score 0):

The command [`mat2cell`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/mat2cell.html) does exactly this. Suppose `A` is your original matrix. Then

```
splitA = mat2cell(A, 300, 50*ones(1, 8));
```

will do what you want.